# Обновление одной записи в базе

Tags: sql, база-данных

Как обновить только одну строку из базы?

Я изменяю информацию в одной из ячеек *datagrid*-a через *текстбокс*, но изначально не знаю — какую. А запрос помещаю под кнопку.

Как сформировать запрос? Может быть, как-то можно получить название колонки с выделенной (или изменённой) ячейкой?

Может быть можно вот так:

```
UPDATE table SET (name=@p1, ...)
WHERE (выделенная ячейка(изменённая) = textbox1.text)
```

тогда как получить информацию об изменённой или выделенной ячейке?

Да, у меня интерфейс - *DataGrid*. И изначально я не знаю, какую я хочу отредактировать ячейку и в какой строке, а запрос на обновление у меня по кнопке стоит. Поэтому я не знаю, как указать в запросе ту строку, в которой изменения произошли.

вот фото формы: `http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120325/3n0yxz7U.jpg` (ссылка нерабочая).

Comment: каким-то образом передавайте идентификатор записи непосредственно с клиента и, соответственно, в SQL запросе - укажите условие вида `primary key = ID_присланный_клиентом`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `example`='value' WHERE `id`='123'");
```

А если у вас в интерфейс, отпишитесь в ответах. Есть идея.

Comment: Да, у меня интерфейс - DataGrid. И изначально я не знаю, какую я хочу отредактировать ячейку и в какой строке, а запрос на обновление у меня по кнопке стоит. Поэтому я не знаю как указать в запросе ту строку, в которой изменения произошли.

Comment: Ни один язык мира не обладает экстрасенсорными способностями, соответственно, если вы до сих пор этого не поняли - с клиента, вместе с данными, нужно отправлять и идентификатора.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас однозначно существует ключевое поле (ID). В DataGrid Вы его можете скрыть. Далее технология очень простая: при выборе записи в таблице (метод выбора сами найдете) "хватаете ID" записи - и, как говорится, все карты в руки.

Comment: а как выбрать запись в таблице? мне её программно выбирать или через запрос?
просто я программно могу получить индекс строки, в которой я изменяю данные. как потом этот индекс в sql запрос перенести

Comment: Естественно программно. Посмотрите какие существуют методы (функции) для Вашего DataGrid. Кстати, судя по скриншоту у Вас клиент на C#? Но возможно ошибаюсь. PS. На Delphi я данную задачу решал таким образом: ставил в "грид" ключевое поле, скрывал от пользователя, при клике по записи выбирал значение Field[0] - и зная необходимую запись...

Comment: да, я могу получить индекс выделенной строки через метод dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

как потом в SQL запрос это всё передать
после UPDATE Cart SET name = @p1,... WHERE Код_карточки = +"dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index"+
или как?